# Riddle from Harry Potter

Tags: riddle, literature

This is a riddle from the 7th Harry Potter book. Who am I?

> I christen myself to the rightful lord, there is nothing I cannot overpower;
>   A crimson splattered history, I was stolen at the top of a tower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its the

> Elder Wand

I christen myself to the rightful lord,

> It only works with the right person

there is nothing I cannot overpower;

> Most powerful wand there is

A crimson splattered history,

> Many killed for it

I was stolen at the top of a tower.

> It was

Irony here is

> Tom **Riddle**